# How do i get my css3 animation smooth?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my portfolio lately, but the problem is that the image animation that i wrote jitters in the end.

[Here is a link to the website](http://www.gummybaar.com/)

Here is the code:

```css
  @keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    50% {top: 25px;}
    100%   {top: 0px;}
    }
    
    img {
        animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/small/basketball_PNG1096.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the movement is very little and the animation duration is long (in your case `25px` in 5 seconds), that means less values to interpolate over a long duration.

If you increase the `top` value or decrease the `duration` (better if you do both), you won't have this jagged animation

Answer (score 0):

have u tried "ease-in-out"

```
@keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        top: 0px;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        top: 25px;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }

    100% {
        top: 0px;
    }
}

img{
   animation: mymove 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to the img. This may prevent re-flow of the page. Also a transform property might help passing the work to GPU, hence smoother animation.

```css
  @keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    50% {top: 25px;}
    100%   {top: 0px;}
    }
    
    img {
        animation: mymove 2s infinite;
        position:absolute;
        transform: translateZ(0);
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/small/basketball_PNG1096.png">
```

Comment: Again, the animation is still choppy at the end

Comment: Sorry, I meant position absolute.

Comment: The duration is 5s and not 2s

Answer (score 0):

```
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.morph {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}

.morph:hover {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,.6), inset 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,.6), inset 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,.6), inset 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

}

---

```
<div class="morph img"><img alt="" src="img/image1.jpg" /></div>
```

Please check this link:-http://1stwebdesigner.com/css3-animation-styles/#css3-animation